# Verification of ODE Solution with Leibnitz's Formula

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Use Leibnitz's formula to establish that

$Z_n = \frac{d^n}{dx^n}e^{-x^2/2}$

is a solution to the differential equation

$\frac{d^2 Z_n}{dx^2} + x\frac{dZ_n}{dx} + (n+1)Z_n = 0$.

I have Leibnitz's formula as

$\frac{d^n(fg)}{dx^n} = \sum_{m=0}^{n} {n \choose m}f^{(n-m)}g^{(m)}$.

Substituting into the ODE and performing the relevant derivatives to get everything in terms of $\frac{d^n}{dx^n}$, I end up with

$\frac{d^n}{dx^n} (x^2e^{-x^2/2}) -x \frac{d^n}{dx^n} (xe^{-x^2/2}) + n \frac{d^n}{dx^n}(e^{-x^2/2})$.

Assuming this is right, I can't seem to figure out how to get the relevant terms in the summations to cancel- I have seen it for a simple trial case ($n=1$) but can't show in generality that the above sums to $0$. I appreciate it's not particularly exciting and only algebraic manipulation, but any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, the second function is $Z_2=\displaystyle \frac{d^2}{dx^2} (e^{-x^2/2})=(x^2-1)e^{-x^2/2}$. Next, notice that most derivatives of the terms $(-x)$ and $(x^2-1)$ are zero, so we can explicitly write

$$ \begin{array}{lll} \displaystyle \frac{d^n}{dx^n} \left[(-x)e^{-x^2/2}\right] & = & \displaystyle \phantom{=}\binom{n}{1}(-x)'(e^{-x^2/2})^{(n-1)} \\ & & \displaystyle +\binom{n}{0}(-x)(e^{-x^2/2})^{(n)} \\[8pt] \displaystyle \frac{d^n}{dx^n}\left[(x^2-1)e^{-x^2/2}\right] & = & \displaystyle \phantom{+} \binom{n}{2}(x^2-1)''(e^{-x^2/2})^{(n-1)} \\ & & \displaystyle +\binom{n}{1}(x^2-1)'(e^{-x^2/2})^{(n-1)} \\ & & \displaystyle +\binom{n}{0}(x^2-1)(e^{-x^2/2})^{(n)} \end{array} $$

Can you take it from here? Putting these in the ODE, cancellation should occur until you arrive at an inductive hypothesis (use strong induction and handle $Z_0$ and $Z_1$ as base cases).

Comment: Perfect- yes taken from here, think I'd just worked myself into a corner. Thanks so much!!